# Calculate GOP size MP4

Tags: mp4, ffprobe

I found a solution to calculate the GOP size of a H264 file.
However when I change the input.h264 to mp4. I get an error that says invalid data.

```
ffprobe -show_frames input.h264 | grep pict_type
```

How can I perform this command line instruction with mp4 video files?

Comment: How did you convert to MP4?

Comment: @Gyan I got an MP4 files

Comment: Share full log of ffprobe run on the MP4.